# I can't access appsync service with aws educate aacount

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-appsync

I'm enrolled in aws educate account and i have to learn appsync service. when i go to the appsync service. it is showing error that i am not authorized to access this. i am attaching error picture.

[Error Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQbZ.png)
Thankyou.

Comment: Hi Muhammed Shariq and welcome to SO. It seems that your question is not code, but service related. That means that there is little for us to help you with. You might get better help by contacting the [AWS Subscriber support services](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) or by visiting the [AWS Knowledge center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/?nc1=f_dr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Educate account is **very limited**, and you can't do what you want to do.

General list of their restrictions is [here](https://awseducate-starter-account-services.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_Educate_Starter_Account_Services_Supported.pdf). Important to note is that:

> All services may have **additional restrictions not listed** below [in the link provided].